# Summing two values from different dataframes if certain criteria is matched python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to sum two columns, each in different frame if certain criteria is met.

Dataframe 1:

```
desk    Type   total_position
desk1   ES     786.0
desk1   ES1    100
desk2   ES1    0
desk2   ES2    10
desk3   ES     0
desk4   ES1    0
desk5   ES     -757
```

Dataframe 2:

```
desk    Type total_position
desk1   ES   -758.0
desk2   ES    0
desk3   ES   -29
desk4   ES    0.0
desk5   ES    786.0
```

I would like to sum both the positions if only the type is "ES" in the first dataframe and it is the same desk.

How do i do that?

Expected Answer

```
desk    Type   total_position
desk1   ES     29
desk2   ES1    0
desk3   ES     -29
desk4   ES1    0
desk5   ES     29
```

Comment: Why not merge the dataframes first. That way you no longer have 2 data frames. Then create a subset for only ES, then add a column with the sum

Comment: the two dataframes are of different sizes actually, gave a simple example for illustration.

Comment: even if the 2 dfs are of different sizes, you can still merge!!

Comment: there is no type column in df2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would `map` and then `add`:

```
df1['total_position'] = (df1['total_position'].add(
               df1['desk'].map(df2.set_index('desk')['total_position']))
print(df1)
```

---

```
    desk Type  total_position
0  desk1   ES            28.0
1  desk2  ES1             0.0
2  desk3   ES           -29.0
3  desk4  ES1             0.0
4  desk5   ES            29.0
```

EDIT for type:

```
m = (df1['desk'].map(df2.set_index('desk')['total_position'])
    .where(df1['Type'].eq('ES')).fillna(0))

df1['total_position'] = df1['total_position'].add(m)
print(df1)

    desk Type  total_position
0  desk1   ES            28.0
1  desk2  ES1             0.0
2  desk3   ES           -29.0
3  desk4  ES1             0.0
4  desk5   ES            29.0
```

Comment: the type is also important. how to consider that?

Comment: yes each desk have multiple types, edited the question

Comment: @lakesh Edited for meeting the type requirement

Comment: one more qn, what if there is desk with a position in df2 but there is no such desk in df1? for desk6, it in df2 but not in df1, does it still work?

Comment: @lakesh then it not find a match and will not be considered in the addition. only matching items from df2 will be returned in df1

Comment: @lakesh in that case what do you want the type column to be assigned since desk6 is in df2 but not df1 and type column is not present in df2.. i guess it will be better as a new question itself but i will try..

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

add via the index, and update the missing values from df1 using `combine_first`

```
df1.set_index('desk').add(df2.set_index('desk')).combine_first(df1.set_index('desk'))
```

NB: this works on the naive assumption that desk in df1 is same in df2.

```
      Type  total_position
desk        
desk1   ES      28.0
desk2   ES1     0.0
desk3   ES     -29.0
desk4   ES1     0.0
desk5   ES      29.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `where`

```
>>> df['total_position'] = (df.total_position+df1.total_position).where(df.desk.eq(df1.desk) & df.Type.eq('ES'), 0)
>>> df
    desk Type  total_position
0  desk1   ES            28.0
1  desk2  ES1             0.0
2  desk3   ES           -29.0
3  desk4  ES1             0.0
4  desk5   ES            29.0
```

Comment: how to make sure the desk also matches?

Comment: You Add multiple condition in `where` like `....where(df['Type'].eq('ES') & d
f['desk'].eq('desk1'))`

Comment: need to sum it based on the desk, not by desk1

Comment: type "ES1" should also have some value and not nan.

Comment: added the expected answer

Comment: @lakesh I have updated answer. although you have now new good answers.